# preg_match regex for time like HH:MM and H:MM

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this regex with

```
preg_match("/(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time)
```

It works fine with `05:00`, etc (with `0` leading) but i would like to accept without the `0` like `5:00` since my mysql field is TIME and accept both i would like to let people give both, since they are going to do that.

Also this should accept `00:30` and of course not `24:30`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty should there be that `+` after the curly braces there?

Comment: wouldn't this accept also 74:00,34:00, etc ? @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: @Miguel Wouldn't your current regexp also catch 05:00 in the string `55959505:00` ?

Comment: -1 Found 813 results with 'preg_match regex for time'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\:+[0-5][0-9]$/`

```
01:00 valid
 5:00 valid
23:59 valid
30:00 invalid
24:00 invalid
00:00 valid
23:90 invalid
```

Just add the question mark really.

Comment: yeah your right, what you mean with "Just add the question mark really"? does i really need to scape ":" ?

Comment: The `?` makes the `[01]` optional, either `none or one of`.  http://www.regexr.com/ experiment, regex is really easy, once you have learned the look-arounds there is nothing left to learn.

Comment: nice website , i always used http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html but it's too complicated. Thanks

Comment: @Flosculus: "regex is really easy, once you have learned the look-arounds there is nothing left to learn" I have to respectfully disagree with at least the second part :) Also, no need to escape the `:` indeed.

Comment: And why the `:+`? This matches `23:::10` now

Comment: @Robin I have a habit of escaping anything that can hold special meaning.  And `:+` because even with multiple colons a valid time can still be extrapolated.

Comment: Or you could equally return something that's not supposed to be a time. It's your choice, but since it changes what the original regex matches I think OP should be made aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess by adding two question marks (optionals):

```
preg_match("/(2?[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/", $time)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected:

```
 preg_match("/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $inputToCheck)
```

- Added ? to make the 0 or 1 prefix optional
- Added ^ and $ to ensure the comparision uses the whole input
- Allows 24 hour format restricted from 0:00  to 24:59
- Allows both HH:MM and H:MM format